# Google assistant "No module named googles...."

Tags: python, windows, google-assistant-sdk

Whenever I run this command

```
py -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers -client-secrets <secrete-location>
```

I get an error saying:

```
C:\Users\chand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe:
  No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers
```

I'm not sure what the issue is as it worked on a different device with the same steps.

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: I think 0.3.0 i'm not sure. How can i check that?

Comment: `python -m pip show google-assistant-sdk`

Comment: Also make sure you are running this command from the virtualenv where you `pip install`ed the `google-assistant-sdk` package

Comment: @proppy i'm using version 0.3.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per version `0.3.0` of the SDK the gRPC samples are using a different auth helpers.

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

From there, you should be able to follow the instructions from the [SDK package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-sdk/) and [gRPC package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-grpc)  page and explore the reference [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I didn't enter the voice shell

```
. /home/pi/bin/voice-recognizer-shell.sh
```

then rerun

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/voice-recognizer-raspi $ ./src/main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same Issue and I used these commands

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]

google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk- prototype \
  --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \
  --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json
```

Be Sure to replace the path to client_Secrets file.

It worked for me. Hope this helps.