# Unable to register Google Assistant Device Model

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying ever so hard to get the Google Assistant on my Windows 10 PC. I am up to the "Register Device" part. 
[Developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device)
Says to run the following command to register your device.

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" \
          --product-name "Assistant SDK light" --type LIGHT --model my-model
```

Which i conclude for Windows (and me) is:

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" --product-name "Assistant SDK light" --type LIGHT --model Sudda2252
```

But, when i run it, i get the error

```
Error: Error loading client secret: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secret_XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'.
Run the device tool with --client-secrets or --project-id option.
Or copy the client_secret_XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json file in the current directory.
```

So i edit the command to:

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" --product-name "Assistant SDK light" --type LIGHT --model 'Sudda2252' --client-secrets "C:\Users\Sudda\Desktop\GoogleAss\client_secret_XXX.json"
```

Where the error is:

```
Error: no such option: --client-secrets
```

Please help where i am going wrong?

P.S. 
 I have tried launching the Google Assistant directly, but it returns an error

```
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance.
```

Refs:

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056237/google-assistant-no-module-named-googles)

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/68dpnj/installing_google_assistant_under_windows_10)

[XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine)

[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device)

Thanks,
Sudda

Edit: My workaround worked once, but then it was useless. Stopped working.

 And thanks @Nick Feller for trying, but didn't work.

 So either i have a problematic computer :D, or we're missing something here.

Comment: Please do not send me [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172989/embed-the-google-assistant-in-a-windows-computer-device-instance-id-not-genera). I have tried it and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think the client secret is not in the right location. It is a parameter of the tool, not of the command. `googlesamples-assistant-devicetool --client-secrets register-model ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very commonly made error - By Google and by the End User - is the naming of your **C**lient **S**ecret file. Google automatically names your **CS** with a (1) appended to the end of your file name. To setup your G Assistant,

1. Delete the (1) in the name
2. Open CMD in the folder with your **CS** (best in a folder with nothing else)
3. Run `googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" --product-name "Assistant SDK light" --type LIGHT --model Sudda2252`
4. Now run `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id ##MODEL## --device-model-id Sudda2252`
   Where ##MODEL## = Your project name.
5. After that, just run `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk` to start G Assistant.

Comment: Edit: Works perfectly, even after a restart! <br> Answer Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

In the [devicetool](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/devicetool.py), the [`--client-secrets`](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/devicetool.py#L112) argument is in relation to the tool itself, not [the command](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/devicetool.py#L228).

The correct order of arguments would be:

`googlesamples-assistant-devicetool --client-secrets register-model ...`